# Build image slider with carouFredSel with this requirements?

Tags: jquery, slider, thumbnails

**GOAL:** To build slider using carouFredSel, to have identical behavior as this one http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html

**EXPLANATION:** There are 5 thumbnails located bellow the main image. Slide should start from the first thumbnail and then after some time next thumbnail must be selected, then next and the next and the next. When it reaches 5th thumbnail, there must be automatic scrolling to next 5 thumbnails. When user hovers over entire slider area, all animation must be stopped.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 600px;">
<div id="slides-images">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"/>
</div>
<div id="slides-thumbs" class="clearfix">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/110x80" /></div>
</div>
<a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/hfMmk/1/

Comment: Waiting for the **QUESTION:**

Comment: Way too specific and localized.

Comment: :D Alright. My question is how to build it, because obviously i have no idea :)

Comment: @RhymeGuy: That's too broad.

Comment: This post is a great example of how specificness and localisedness are orthogonal to one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Build image slider with carouFredSel with this requirements?

No.

Comment: I'm just wondering how many minuses I could receive for this.. :D